# Using noexcept and compiler flags that turn off exceptions

Tags: c++

#### introduction

In embedded c++, and especially in real-time systems there is no need to handle exceptions and if a system is going to crash, in common practice, we let it crash. Every crash is a programmer error, that must be fixed. So there is no need to handle exceptions in a release.

#### problem

Usage of `noexcept` specifier can significantly reduce the size of binary files and increase performance. In this way, every `stl` function inside a function with `noexcept` will call noexcept overload if it is available. But usage of this specifier is restrictive and has a lot of limitations(inheritance, virtual functions signature, compatibility). If you modify source without proper integration, there will be errors like `looser throw specifier for...`.

No exception flag(like g++ `-fno-exceptions`) only replace all `throw` for `abort` and may reduce some stack size.

#### question

Are there any good practices how to use `noexcept` specifier or flags, in the case where it is necessary to upgrade legacy code (before c++11), increase performance and reduce size of binaries? For now, I can see only one way - add `noexcept` to every function.

compilers(arm-none-eabi-g++, C++ compiler MSVC), c++14

Comment: This text somehow states that exception = programmer error = crash. Also use of `noexcept` is equivalent to wrapping function body into `try`...`catch` block cataching any exceptions and calling `std::terminate`. So `noexcept` does not really ensure that there is no exceptions.

Comment: Just because something has raised an exception - doesn't mean it should crash.  It just means something "exceptional" has happened.  For example an `IOBlockException` (like in Java) means that that there's no data available .... and if it's not caught then THAT is the error

Comment: @UKMonkey In embedded, you usually don't want exceptional situation to happen: It is another flow of execution to test and certify, and it is especially difficult to test (because exceptions are not structured programming).

Comment: `Usage of noexcept specifier can significantly reduce the size of binary files and increase performance`  You'll find that it might impact the size of the binary; but there's no change in performance.

Comment: @AdrianMaire "test and certify" just because it's embedded doesn't mean it needs to be certified; just because it's not embedded doesn't mean it doesn't need to be certified.  Exception raising can easily be tested with test objects in the same way you would test non-exception raising.

Comment: "*Usage of noexcept specifier can significantly reduce the size of binary files and increase performance.*" - do you have a source for the latter? I am no embedded expert, but I don't think there is much performance lost, especially in no-exceptional flow. Unless some predictors/program caches are thrown off by extra code. But I've seen no measurements.

Comment: @VTT, a `try-catch` block that calls `terminate` requires stack unwinding to happen before the exception is caught, which requires running any destructors with side-effects. When an exception would exit from a `noexcept` function the compiler is allowed _but not required_ to do any stack unwinding. It can just terminate instead of unwinding to the catch point. So the two cases are not exactly equivalent (and one can produce smaller faster code).

Comment: @JonathanWakely That is why I wrote "equivalent" and not just "equal" or "the same".

Comment: @VTT and my comment says "not exactly equivalent", so other readers won't mistakenly think that's what you meant. In normal English equivalent and equal and identical can be used as synonyms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In this way, every stl function inside a function with `noexcept` will call `noexcept` overload if it is available.

No, because you can't overload on `noexcept`. Marking a function with `noexcept` doesn't affect overload resolution of functions it calls.

The size reduction from marking a function `noexcept` is because the compiler doesn't need to emit code for stack unwinding and exception handling, it can just terminate. But if you use `-fno-exceptions` the compiler also doesn't have to emit code for stack unwinding and exception handling, so you should get the same benefits (without needing to add `noexcept` anywhere).

> Are there any good practices how to use `noexcept` specifier or flags, in the case where it is necessary to upgrade legacy code (before c++11), increase performance and reduce size of binaries?

Good practice is to only add `noexcept` to functions that you know *definitely* can't throw, and which will never be changed to throw, *or* if you definitely want them to call `std::terminate` if an exception does happen.

That doesn't mean adding it to every function.

It also doesn't mean adding it to virtual functions carelessly. Doing so changes the contract of the base class, and requires all overrides to be updated.

Comment: So, is it preferable to use compiler flag when there is no need to handle exceptions?

Comment: If you don't want to deal with exceptions then yes, tell the compiler you don't want to use exceptions (and make sure any libraries you're using will do something else instead of throwing, like abort). It seems obviously better to do that than to still allow exceptions to be thrown and then editing every single function in your code base to terminate.